# How can I change the timezone in mysql using PHPMyAdmin without admin permission

Tags: mysql

I want to display

```
SELECT NOW();
```

as Asia/Hong_Kong time.
Please help...

Comment: How about reading the date/time function for mysql?

Answer (score 8):

ASIA/HONG KONG is GMT+08:00

```
mysql_query("SET SESSION time_zone = '+8:00'");
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you can change time_zone in mysql.

```
SET time_zone = 'Asia/Hong_Kong';
```

For [more reference](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)

Comment: @red23jordan I think you don't have sufficient permission.

Comment: thats only temporary isnt it? like you have to do that for every connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the timezone in the my.ini config file as well.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone

Answer (score 0):

In your file `php.ini`

```
[Date]<br />
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions<br />
; http://php.net/date.timezone<br />
date.timezone ="Africa/Kigali"<br />
```

you need to change the timezone.
[Here is a list of timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
SET time_zone = '+8:00';
```

This seems to work for me in MySQL GoDaddy server. 
Just change +8.00 (Asia/Kuala_Lumpur) to your country timezone.

Comment: HKT – Hong Kong Time (Standard Time) has a Time Zone Indicator: +0800 That means that Asia/Hong_Kong has the same time as Asia/Kuala_Lumpur

Answer (score 0):

My time set automatically with 1 hour advance in real time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

Some MySQL servers may not have the TZ tables loaded - so using the format:

```
SET time_zone = "Asia/Hong Kong";
```

may not work, in which case you will have to instead use the UTC offset format., using a value i.e.

```
SET time_zone = '+10:00';
```

Note: The UTC offset format by its very nature (that you are specifying the offset) doesn't automatically take into account Daylight Saving Times (whereas the named version does as the TZ - TimeZone - tables are loaded into MySQL with that info and are able to do lookups on the DST values).

Answer (score -3):

i use this, hope this coulkd help

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila"); ?>
```

maybe you could use ("Asia/Hong Kong") but not tested

Comment: `Asia/Hong Kong` is not supported. `Asia/Manila` yes. Check the [accepted timezones on the php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.asia.php)