# setting timezone for MySQL using PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Currently whenever a user creates a new account, I have a Creation_date column that has datatype `timestamp`. Currently this timestamp reads 3 hours ahead of EST (if it's 5PM in Boston it reads 8PM). Is there a way to change the timezone to EST? What timezone is it set to currently?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has to do with MySQL's timezone.

You can set it per connection (e.g. via PHPMyAdmin) with the following:

```
SET time_zone = timezone;
```

However, this will *reset* if MySQL restarts. So it is better set at the server level. Which, I assume, you can't.

I encourage you to read more from the [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html).

Comment: ? if MySQL restarts the connection will be broken.

Comment: can you only do it per session? i cant set it to PST permanently?

Answer (score 7):

Accordingly with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798308/how-can-i-change-the-timezone-in-mysql-using-phpmyadmin-without-admin-permission)

```
SET SESSION time_zone = '+8:00'
```

Answer (score 3):

`TIMESTAMP` values are converted to UTC when inserted into the DB and converted back to the current timezone set in MySQL on retrieval.  The other answers show how to set the timezone in MySQL which will determine what value comes out of the database.

Another option is to use a `DATETIME` column, store ALL of your dates in UTC, and convert them to the desired timezone in your application (PHP or wherever you get the values from).

Answer (score 2):

SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;

Comment: e.g. for India SET GLOBAL time_zone = "+05:30";

Answer (score 1):

This is a COMPLETE example, for Argentina

```sql
SET GLOBAL time_zone = "-03:00";
```

you just need to change the "-03:00" for your timezone and run that command like a simple query, even in PhpMyAdmin.