# Changing the default TimeZone of phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, timezone, timestamp

> I created a QueryLog table and had a column of date-time. I set the default value to that as timestamp, but the timestamp is 2 hours earlier. How can I set the default timestamp to my time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your file php.ini

```
[Date]<br />
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions<br />
; http://php.net/date.timezone<br />
date.timezone ="Africa/Kigali"<br />
```

For More detail [time-zone-support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

Please Refer this SO Question: [setting-timezone-for-mysql-using-phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853534/setting-timezone-for-mysql-using-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the default timezone of Database.

Go to app.php page in Config folder and change this

`'timezone' => 'UTC',`
to
`'timezone' => 'Asia/Dhaka',`// You need to adjust your timezone based on your location.

reference https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration
find your timezone http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php